# Cookie set in ajax is not posted on get http call

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies, servicestack

SPA app, the specific requirements are:

1. Client calls api through ajax. Server responds with cookie header, among other things such as body.

   Set-Cookie: Auth=79c6fdfe12754560a2b5a62600df3215:INq8DnQ2a27MrEuFC8WKeoeoLH0r3H0y5UM9B95UL6M=; expires=Thu, 30-Jun-2016 08:02:37 GMT; domain=.example.com; path=/; HttpOnly
2. Client has a link for a specific feature which if clicked, navigate to the api server. This api is open to receive non-ajax get http calls but requires authentication. The cookie is expected for this purpose.

Tested in both IE/firefox, cookie isn't being sent on get http call for step 2.

The api server is ws-dev.example.com and SPA is loaded from fe-dev.example.com.

Comment: It would help to see how you're making the AJAX call to the server.  Is your server properly configured for CORS?  Are you setting the `withCredentials` flag in `xhrFields` (if you're using jQuery)?

Comment: For sending cookie part of ajax I understand that withCredentials is needed. However, is it also needed for browser to accept cookie from an ajax call and store it. And then send it if browser is navigated to that domain url (non-ajax call)?

Comment: @PatrickSteele Thanks. Been going round and round in circles for hours trying to work out what was wrong with my test system, and re-checking my CORS settings and using xhrFields worked :)